# Sending data from api to my app via firebase cloud messaging

Tags: android

i have an app where i get certain data like date , time , team 1 and  team 2 from sport api , i want to use FCM to show a notification with data every time ( my notifications are for football live games of premier league , so when games start playing , a notification should pop up in the user app ), is it possible to send data from api to my app via FCM to show a notification  , i ve read a little bit about FCM HTTP V1 , but i'm still not sure wether it does the job or not , any suggestions guys , thank you .

Comment: you can send your JSON based on your function in this API `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` together with your Firebase project Legacy server key and capture it android using NotificationService that extend in FirebaseMessagingService

Comment: thank you for the reply , do you have any piece of code showing how to do that , i didnt find much about it searchng on google

Comment: Sorry this is not how stackoverflow work and what your asking is a function of FCM notification which cannot be shared just by a "piece" of code. I recommended you create first NotificationService in android and test it manually in Firebase Cloud Messaging Dashboard

Comment: To make it dynamic/automatic you can trigger an AsyncTask that send JSON data on the https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send targeting specific user, multiple user or via subscription topic

Comment: i already did implement firebase and everything is fine , i create service class which extends FirebaseMessagingService , where it override OnMessageReceived , and i also have the json object of my matches ready , i only couldnt understand the part of sending the json data to google api link

Comment: can you post your sample JSON?

Comment: This is sample of json file https://pastebin.com/cUhbRsXR ( i want to only retreive four values which are : time , date , home team and away team ) , that"s what i want to pass to my notification

Comment: do you want notify a specific users or all users?

Comment: I want to send the same notifications to all users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send JSON that target a specific Topic to all user that subscribe to that Topic.
You can subscribe the user in the that topic by calling this

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("your_topic");
```

Once subscribe you can send this JSON to the API https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

```
{
 "to":"/topics/your_topic",

  "notification": {
  "title": "Title Message"
  "body": "Body Message"
  },

  "data": {
   "time": "your time"
   "date": "your date"
   "home_team": "your home team"
   "away_team": "your away team"
  }
```

together with your headers `"Content-Type", "application/json"` and `"Authorization", "key=your_FCM_legacy_server_key"`

it's up to you on how you handle that "data" on your NotificationService

this how you handle the data in this part of JSON

```
"data": {
       "time": "your time"
       "date": "your date"
       "home_team": "your home team"
       "away_team": "your away team"
      }
```

handle it like this

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();

        String time= data.get("time");
        String date= data.get("date");
        String home_team= data.get("home_team");
        String home_away= data.get("home_away");

        String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(); //retrieve the notification body
        String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(); //retrieve  the notification title

}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202027/discussion-on-answer-by-l2-paver-sending-data-from-api-to-my-app-via-firebase-cl).